# What does "P2P peers available. Skipped DNS seeding" means?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin-core-development

I'm trying to avoid bitcoin daemon trying to connect to other addresses but the ones that I set in bitcoin.conf.

I've commented `vSeeds` in chainparams.cpp and I've cleared vFixedSeeds in this way:

`vFixedSeeds = std::vector<SeedSpec6>(pnSeed6_main, pnSeed6_main + ARRAYLEN(pnSeed6_main));
        vFixedSeeds.clear();`

But the daemon still tries to connect with some addresses. What I am missing?

What I need to do is to connect two bitcoin daemons that are running in the same machine, with a different genesis block than the main blockchain (both daemons share the same genesis block).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bitcoin Core does not solely rely on the DNS seeders to find nodes to connect to. The peer discovery system first starts with a local database of known nodes that it gathers after having had connections. DNS seeding or fall back seed nodes are only used if the peers database is empty, i.e. the first time you run the software. So this message means that the peers database is not empty, so it will skip the DNS seeders and go straight to connecting to peers from the database.

> What I need to do is to connect two bitcoin daemons that are running in the same machine, with a different genesis block than the main blockchain (both daemons share the same genesis block).

Use the `-connect=<ip>:<port>` startup option. This option means that the node will connect only to the specified IP address and port and nothing else; it won't do any other peer discovery.